# How does OpenGL lighting works?

Tags: c++, opengl

i want to know how is OpenGL's glLightfv() works i mean if a glortho is set to (10, -10, 10, -10, 10, -10) then if a traingle's vertices are within 5 (eg. glVertex3f(0, 5, 0), glVertex3f(-5, -5, -5) and so on until a 3d triangle is created) then where should i place the light?? From most tutorials they were 1, 1, 1, 0. but by this my Model which is a colour full 3d triangle, becomes full White, can anyone here make me understand how can the lighting function of opengl be used in program, with shadoes and colour, i hope i was clear, thanks in advance!!

Comment: glLight stuff is deprecated. You should look up modern OpenGL.

Comment: [Don't use old OpenGL](http://kos.gd/2012/11/dont-use-old-opengl/)

Comment: And whats Old and New?? I have visited many sites showing tutorials for lights using gllightfv() but i heard a new thing here, Modern!! Can u pls tell whats it, am i using an older version of Opengl?? And why should i update is it neccessary??